# How to draw a decent looking Circle in Java

Tags: java, graphics, antialiasing, geometry

I have tried using the method drawOval with equal height and width but as the diameter increases the circle becomes worse looking. What can I do to have a decent looking circle no matter the size. How would I implement anti-aliasing in java or some other method.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As it turns out, Java2D (which I'm assuming is what you're using) is already pretty good at this!  There's a decent tutorial here: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1998/jw-08-media.html

The important line is:

```
graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                          RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Comment: It looks like the constants have been moved from Graphics2D to RenderingHints. See [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/Graphics2DsetRenderingHintKeyhintKeyObjecthintValue.htm).

Comment: 19 years and still counting =P

Comment: 20 and still lives!  :ㅇ

Comment: 21 years, yahoo :)

Comment: 22 let's go! XD

Comment: Nope. Page not found

Comment:  That link to a Bill Day article from June of 1998 was still good 10 years after Sun Microsystems went offline. Godspeed, article written about the new features of Java 1.2.

Answer (score 33):

you can set rendering hints:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Answer (score 18):

Two things that may help:

1. Use `Graphics2D.draw(Shape)` with an instance of `java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D` instead of `Graphics.drawOval`
2. If the result is still not satisfactory, try using `Graphics2D.setRenderingHint` to enable antialiasing

Example

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    Shape theCircle = new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, 2.0 * radius, 2.0 * radius);
    g2d.draw(theCircle);
}
```

See Josef's answer for an example of `setRenderingHint`

Answer (score 7):

Of course you set your radius to what ever you need:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    Ellipse2D.Double hole = new Ellipse2D.Double();
    hole.width = 28;
    hole.height = 28;
    hole.x = 14;
    hole.y = 14;
    g2d.draw(hole);
}
```

Comment: You also need to set the position of the ellipse, and I think you want g2d.draw not g2d.stroke

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Oleg Estekhin for pointing out the bug report, because it explains how to do it.

Here are some small circles before and after. Magnified a few times to see the pixel grid.

[image: Circles before and after]

Going down a row, they're moving slightly by subpixel amounts.

The first column is without rendering hints. The second is with antialias only. The third is with antialias and pure mode.

Note how with antialias hints only, the first three circles are the same, and the last two are also the same. There seems to be some discrete transition happening. Probably rounding at some point.

Here's the code. It's in Jython for readability, but it drives the Java runtime library underneath and can be losslessly ported to equivalent Java source, with exactly the same effect.

```
from java.lang import *
from java.io import *
from java.awt import *
from java.awt.geom import *
from java.awt.image import *
from javax.imageio import *

bim = BufferedImage(30, 42, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
g = bim.createGraphics()
g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
g.setColor(Color.BLACK)
for i in range(5):
    g.draw(Ellipse2D.Double(2+0.2*i, 2+8.2*i, 5, 5))

g.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.  KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)

for i in range(5):
    g.draw(Ellipse2D.Double(12+0.2*i, 2+8.2*i, 5, 5))

g.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.  KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE)

for i in range(5):
    g.draw(Ellipse2D.Double(22+0.2*i, 2+8.2*i, 5, 5))

#You'll probably want this too later on:
#g.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.  KEY_INTERPOLATION,
#                    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC)
#g.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.  KEY_RENDERING, 
#                    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY)

ImageIO.write(bim, "PNG", File("test.png"))
```

Summary: you need both `VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON` and `VALUE_STROKE_PURE` to get proper looking circles drawn with subpixel accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

Inability to draw a "decent looking circle" is related to the very old bug [6431487](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6431487).

Turning antialiasing on does not help a lot - just check the kind of "circle" produced by the drawOval() or drawShape(Eclipse) when the required circle size is 16 pixels (still pretty common for icon size) and antialiasing is on. Bigger antialiased circles will look better but they are still asymmetric, if somebody will care to look at them closely.

It seems that to draw a "decent looking circle" one has to manually draw one. Without antialiasing it will be midpoint circle algorithm (this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022178/how-to-make-a-circle-on-a-grid) has an answer with a pretty java code for it).

Answer (score -2):

EDITED: 06 September 2017

That's an algorithm invented by me to draw a circle over a integer matrix. The same idea could be used to write a circle inside a BufferedImage.
If you are trying to draw that circle using the class Graphics this is not the answare you are looking for (unless you wish to modify each color-assignement with g.drawLine(x, y, x+1, y), but it could be very slow).

```
protected boolean runOnCircumference(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int ray, int color) {
    boolean ret;
    int[] rowUpper = null, rowInferior = null, rowCenterUpper = null, rowCenterInferior = null;

    if (ret = ray > 0) {
        if (ray == 1) {
            matrix[y][x + 1] = color;
            rowUpper = matrix[++y];
            rowUpper[x] = color;
            rowUpper[x + 2] = color;
            matrix[y][x] = color;
        } else {
            double rRay = ray + 0.5;
            int r = 0, c = 0, ray2 = ray << 1, ray_1 = ray - 1, halfRay = (ray >> 1) + ray % 2, rInf,
                    ray1 = ray + 1, horizontalSymmetricOldC;
            // draw cardinal points

            rowUpper = matrix[ray + y];
            rowUpper[x] = color;
            rowUpper[x + ray2] = color;
            matrix[y][x + ray] = color;
            matrix[ray2 + y][x + ray] = color;

            horizontalSymmetricOldC = ray1;
            rInf = ray2;
            c = ray_1;
            for (r = 0; r < halfRay; r++, rInf--) {

                rowUpper = matrix[r + y];
                rowInferior = matrix[rInf + y];

                while (c > 0 && (Math.hypot(ray - c, (ray - r)) < rRay)) {

                    rowUpper[x + c] = color;
                    rowUpper[x + horizontalSymmetricOldC] = color;
                    rowInferior[x + c] = color;
                    rowInferior[x + horizontalSymmetricOldC] = color;

                    // get the row pointer to optimize
                    rowCenterUpper = matrix[c + y];
                    rowCenterInferior = matrix[horizontalSymmetricOldC + y];
                    // draw
                    rowCenterUpper[x + r] = color;
                    rowCenterUpper[x + rInf] = color;
                    rowCenterInferior[x + r] = color;
                    rowCenterInferior[x + rInf] = color;
                    horizontalSymmetricOldC++;
                    c--;
                }
            } // end r circle
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I tried it so many times, verifying manually it correctness, so I think it will work. I haven't made any range-check just to simplify the code.
I hope it will help you and everyone wish to draw a circle over a matrix (for example, those programmer who tries to create their own videogames on pure code and need to manage a matrix-oriented game-map to store the objects lying on the game-map [if you need help on this, email me]).