# draw smooth thin circle in java 2d graphics

Tags: java, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw a decent looking Circle in Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094539/how-to-draw-a-decent-looking-circle-in-java)

hi I drew onw circle with stroke in java by using graphics2d ...but am getting always irregular circle...I am getting circle without smooth...can u plz help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [How to draw a decent looking Circle in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094539/how-to-draw-a-decent-looking-circle-in-java):

Turning on antialiasing helps make things look better:

```
graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

See also: [Antialiasing, images, and alpha compositing in Java 2D](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1998/jw-08-media.html)

Comment: is it Graphics2D.ANTIALIASING built in value?i am getting compilation error when i used this Graphics2D.ANTIALIASING,Graphics2D.ANTIALIAS_ON..wat is tat?

Comment: It appears that the constants have been moved. I have corrected the answer.