# Can not draw oval on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-2d, paintcomponent

I have a JFrame created with GUI builder of Netbeans, which contains a JPanel only. I have created a method `getPanel` for getting a reference to this JPanel:

```
public class ShowDrawings extends JFrame {

    public ShowDrawings() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public JPanel getPanel(){
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel panel;
}
```

In my main function I am doing:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ShowDrawings sd = new ShowDrawings();
        sd.setSize(800, 600);
        Graphics g = sd.getPanel().getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(400, 300, 50, 50);
        sd.getPanel().paint(g);
        sd.repaint();
        sd.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But it does not draw anything. Please help me.
I have looked some related questions but they are all suggesting extending `JPanel` and overriding its `paint` method. But I did not want to do that way.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using GUI builder of Netbeans,it should not cause any problem.I have used it many times.Can you please post full code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have looked some related questions but they are all suggesting
>   extending `JPanel` and overriding its `paint` method. But I did not want
>   to do that way

You should not override `JPanel` `paint()` method, rather `paintComponent(..)`. This is best practice and should be done if you want code that will not produce anomalies. Also doing it in your current approach (as you have seen) makes creating persistent drawings a lot harder as they are wiped away on `repaint()`

Rather extend `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` not forgetting to call `super.paintComponent(g)` as first call in overridden `paintComponent(..)` method. Also dont forget to override `getPreferredSize()` of `JPanel` so that we can return correct dimensions and `pack()` may be called on `JFrame` (+1 to @mKorbels comment):

Here is some example code:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel testPanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
                super.paintComponent(grphcs);

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;

                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                //g2d.drawOval(10,10,100,100);//I like fill :P
                g2d.fillOval(10,10,100,100);

            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(150, 150);
            }
        };

        frame.add(testPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: For circles and other ellipses, you might want to also `g.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.  KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,                        RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31221395/1143274

Answer (score 3):

The first time you `repaint()` your `ShowDrawings sd` frame anything you've painted like this (`sd.getPanel().getGraphics().drawOval(...)`) would be erased by the original `JPanel#paintComponent()` method.

As [Andrew Thompson has written](http://pscode.org/guifaq.html#2.4):

> Do not use Component.getGraphics(). Instead, subclass and override the paint() (AWT), or paintComponent() (Swing) method.
>
> Component.getGraphics() simply can't work. Java uses a callback mechanism for drawing graphics. You are not supposed to "push" graphics information into a component using getGraphics(). Instead you are supposed to wait until Java calls your **paint()/paintComponent()** method. At that moment you are supposed to provide the Component with the drawings you would like to do.

If you're just checking/debugging something you could even do something like this:

```
class Test {
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
             g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
             g.drawOval(400, 300, 50, 50);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: and then have to override PreferredSize for JPanel :-)