# Inaccurate Graphics2D.draw(Shape) method

Tags: java, swing, animation, draw, graphics2d

I make a game and when I animate entity with low velocity I use `g.FILL(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, r, r));` because it renders smooth and fluent motion.

It work fine *(in Example blue left circle)*. But when I needed just an outline of circle I used `g.DRAW(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, w, h));` and it didn't work and I absolutely don't know what's wrong. No fluent motion, circle jumps pixel over pixel and it looks ugly *(in Example red right circle)*. `Graphics2D.draw(Shape)` count float values like int values.

This Example code demonstrate it, don't study it a lot, just import, run and watch.

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) { new Example(); }

    public Example() {

        setBounds(50, 50, 400, 400);
        setVisible(true);

        while(true) {
            x1 += 0.01;
            y1 += 0.01;
            x2 -= 0.01;
            y2 += 0.01;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(16);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    double x1 = 50 , y1 = 50;
    double x2 = 250, y2 = 50;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics gg) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gg;
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x1, y1, 100, 100));
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x2, y2, 100, 100));
    }
}
```

So how can I fix it without tricks like filling two cirle or moving image of circle? Thanks for every answer.

Comment: 1) *"..just import, run and watch."*  It won't compile without imports, nor run without a `main(String)` why don't you just add them?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) `setBounds(50, 50, 400, 400);` Instead return a sensible preferred size and `pack()`.. 3) `while(true) {..`  Not the way to animate in Swing.  Better to use a Swing `Timer` to call `repaint()`..

Answer (score 2):

I would guess the problem is that you didn't invoke super.paint(...) as the first statement in the method which means you lose some of the default painting functionality.

However, that is NOT the proper solution as you should NOT be overriding the paint() method of a JFrame at all. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...) method of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Also, don't use a while true loop for animation. Instead you should be using a `Swing Timer` to schedule the animation (the tutorial has a section on Swing Timers). Your code only works because you are NOT creating the GUI correctly. The GUI should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread. The Custom Painting tutorial shows you how to use the `invokeLater(...)` method to do this. The tutorial also has a section on `Concurrency in Swing` which explains this concept in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I could repair these mistakes, but many of them I did just because I wanted to cut long annoying code to something short and easy. However code exactly demonstrate the bug that wasn't solved by any of your advice.

Comment: @user2204493, `However code exactly demonstrate the bug that wasn't solved by any of your advice.` - post your updated code that shows how you implemented the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

With drawing circles/ovals/ellipses in Java, the "pure" mode often helps drawing it with subpixel accuracy:

```
g.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.  KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE)
```

My other answer has more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31221395/1143274