# Issues with drawing multiple circles (drawOval / Java)

Tags: java, graphics, paintcomponent

My issues is the following: My actual project (of which the code below is a simplified version of) involves many concentric circles (each with a different colour) and animation utilising a Timer. The circles are drawn using the *drawOval* method.

My problem is that when these concentric circles are drawn, there appears to be loads of gaps in the outline of these circles, which I'm guessing is something to do with the fact that a circle is composed of pixels and lines as is any shape so the appearance of roundness is an illusion. I say this because when I swap the *drawOval* method for *drawRect* the painting looks as you would expect.

When messing around with other people's codes I saw that using RenderingHints somehow solved this problem however slowed down the animation beyond a point that I felt was acceptable.

Below is a screenshot of what is painted. Rather than seeing a solid opaque circle (as all of the circles drawn have the same colour in this example) we see this:

[image: what we actually see]

Here is my simplified code:

**Test10**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
public class Test10 extends JPanel {
Circle[] circles;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test10().go();
    }
    void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle Test");
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        circles = new Circle[200];
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            circles[i] = new Circle(i, ((2 * ( 200 - i) + 1)));
        }
        repaint();
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for (Circle circle : circles ) {
            circle.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

**Circle**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;    
public class Circle {
int topLeft;
int diameter;
    public Circle(int topLeft, int diameter) {
        this.topLeft = topLeft;
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }
    void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(topLeft, topLeft, diameter, diameter);

    }
}
```

Could anyone explain to me a) **Why** this is happening and b) **How** to overcome this problem.
**UPDATE**
Having tried various methods including starting with the outermost circle and using *fillOval* instead of *drawOval*, and using a higher *stroke* value, I still find I have a problem with certain artefacts appearing similar to the screenshot Pavel posted. Here is a screenshot from my full application running the animation, if you look carefully you can see inconsistencies in the colour of mostly any given circle, resulting in these strange results. Their distribution actually follows the same pattern as the screenshot posted above so clearly something fundamental isn't being addressed by these options. Here is my screen shot:
[image: my full application in action]

Comment: Wouldn't drawing a single filled circle or two concentric filled circles do the trick?

Comment: See the top of my post, in the full application every circle has a different colour, creating a pretty series of concentric circles. This is the reason I'm not using fillOval, thanks anyway :P

Comment: Are you implementing a hypnotoad from Futurama? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to draw perfect circle.

Try using the following method

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        int i = 0;
        for (Circle circle : circles ) {
            Shape circle2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(i++, i, circle.diameter, circle.diameter);
            g2d.draw(circle2);
        }
    }
```

You said you tried with `RenderingHints`, and it slowed your animation, but you haven't give us any code with animation, so maybe try my code (it would be good to see animation implementation). It looked better, but still not what you wanted. Setting stroke to another value will solve this (set to at least 2). Another one is to use `.fill()` instead of `.draw()`. I know that it is not perfect, but you may try it.

**ANOTHER IDEA**

I thought, that maybe you could add some blur to your image, so those artifacts are not visible?
I haven't done it before, but I found this ([found HERE](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1360058)):

```
private class BlurGlass extends JComponent {
        private JFrame f;

        public BlurGlass(JFrame f) {
            this.f = f;
            setOpaque(false);
            setFocusable(false);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int w = f.getWidth();
            int h = f.getHeight();
            setLocation(0, 0);
            setSize(w, h);
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.3f));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        }
    }
```

now somwhere in `go()` method:

```
frame.setGlassPane(new BlurGlass(frame));
frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
```

It looks a lot better for me. Play a bit with this GlassPane color (try changing .3f to some other value).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I've tried all of them but I still get weird artefacts, as in individual circles do not maintain their exact colour throughout, noticably in the NE NW SW and SE directions. Let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: New information looks great, will give it a go later, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make the [Stroke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html) bigger. I've had luck with this in situations similar to yours

Comment: Thanks will have a play with this later, looks hopeful.

Comment: Gave it a go, have made an update to my original post to show what results this gives as they are not ideal. This method certainly helps however there is still a problem with it. Thanks for the help and would greatly appreciate if you'd take a look at the update :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding this line in your Circle class inside draw function:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
//and draw the Oval on g2
```

Also another solution might be to fill the circles:

```
Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, diameter, diameter);
g2.fill(circle);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, see update for details on why a problem persists. Very good suggestions though I need to familiarize myself with rendering hints. More help would be appreciated.

Comment: Another approach would be to have some predefined images of concentric circles and gradually revealing the image. Too bad it's not a programatical solution it might give you better graphics.

Comment: Meh, the full application is an animation where each frame contains a series of concentric circles with RGB components going up in specified increments. As each frame progresses the circles pass their colour onto the circle outside of them giving the effect of a wormhole. Kind of needs to be programatical right?

Comment: And I have a final idea. Try to apply a blur filter to see if it looks a bit better.
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/ImageEffectSharpenblur.htm

Answer (score 0):

That happens because a computer cannot draw a perfect circle.

A computer uses square pixels to approximate a real circle but its just not possible to achieve perfection and that results in some pixels not being shown

Drawing a filled circle will help you

[a detailed explanation](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~sarasu/courses/comp175-2009fa/pdf/comp175-03-lines-circles.pdf)

Comment: As I suspected, thanks very much. My problem has not been solved and I've added details to my question if you're still interested in helping, greatly appreciate that link, will have a good read later!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try fillOval method instead of drawOval.

```
g.fillOval(topLeft, topLeft, diameter, diameter);
```

[image]

Comment: Works better on mine than it seems to on yours. Those symmetrical artefacts I can see on your screen print are not desirable. Thanks for the answer though as of yet seems to be the most useful.

Comment: Yeah I get those artefacts too, any clue as to how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your idea. Start with the outermost circle, then draw the inner circle and so on, finishing with the smallest circle. You should use `fillOval` in the process.

Comment: Hi thanks, I've actually already tried this approach and while it works on small scales when a large variety of colours are involved it gives rise to funny artefacts. I've edited my question to include this information alongside another screenshot. Thanks again

Comment: It is because fill oval fills the circle and there is a high difference between the radiuses of your circles. If you want to draw an empty circle with a thick border (to have a perfect circle), then you can drawOval inside your fillOval with almost the same radius.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A high difference between the radiuses of the circles? Adjacent circles differ in radius by 1, so I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Still, try out my improved idea, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The other rendering hint that is often useful for circles/ovals is

```
g.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.  KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
```

See my [other answer with more details and example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31221395/1143274).