# Why oval shape is sinuous and pixelated?

Tags: java

I noticed that the oval shape is a bit sinuous and pixelated:

[image]

How to draw a clear and clean one?

My simple code :

```
 g.drawOval(xCenter - radius, yCenter - radius,
            2 * radius, 2 * radius);
```

Comment: Draw a larger circle

Comment: You'll want to enable anti-aliasing (via `g.addRenderingHints(...)`)

Comment: Because essentially you're drawing a [raster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) and you need to "smudge" it, for lack of a better word, so it looks smooth. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094539/how-to-draw-a-decent-looking-circle-in-java) question for more info.