# How to draw a smooth Oval?

Tags: java, graphics, frame

In order to make a Oval I have to relay on fillOval method of Graphics.
Fact is that its not smooth you might have noticed that boundary is not curve.
It looks petty ugly.
How to draw a smooth Oval?
[Link to the Oval.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bylmr.png)

```
    public void drawBall()
    {
        game.g2d.setStroke(game.narrowStroke);
        game.g2d.fillOval(x-radius,y-radius,diameter,diameter);
        game.g2d.setStroke(game.wideStroke);
    }
    /*
            narrowStroke=new BasicStroke(1f);
            wideStroke=new BasicStroke(10f);
    */
```

Comment: Are you asking how to draw an antialiased oval?

Comment: The problem with above code is that the boundary of the oval is not smooth.

Comment: have a look at this tutorial: [Controlling Rendering Quality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html) and this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1094539/85421)

Comment: RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE);

Comment: still its same.

Comment: Oh! fine in the above comment I have used wrong statement.

Comment: It should be :- RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);                                                                       g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);

Comment: @Carlos thanks for clearing my doubt and sharing the link.