# Divide Polygon Shape Java

Tags: java, graphics, polygon

I have a simple 2D polygon with 4 points.

```
    int[] x = {38, 100, 80, 18};
    int[] y = {50, 50, 100, 100};
    
    Polygon poly = new Polygon(x, y, 4);
```

The above polygon is just an example. The polygon above could really be anything as long as the polygon is always convex, always has 4 points, and is a parallelogram. I need to split it into any number of even parts, all proportional to the bigger polygon, as long as the number is a square number. Is there any simple way I can do this? I am using Graphics on a Jframe if that's important at all.

Comment: "Split it into 8 even parts" What does that mean? Just arbitrarily splitting your polygon into 8 chunks?

Comment: A grid pattern, that is proportional to the original polygon shape.

Comment: Dividing into 2x4? Or 4x2? And you have two sides horizontal (y1 = y2 and y3 = y4), is that a required condition?

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry, the number of portions it gets split into needs to be a power of 2. And yes it must be a parallelogram. Question edited.

Comment: not 4, 9, 16... (n^2) but 2, 4, 8... (2^n) right? You need to decide how you would cut the shape if you want to split it into 8 portions.

Comment: 4, 9, 16..., actually I don't know exactly how to word that. Square number?.

Comment: When dividing into n pieces, each coordinate should be divided by `Math.sqrt(n)`?

Comment: Yes, "[square numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number)". If you want to divide a four-side shape into four parts, you can cut each side half by getting the mid point (since four is a square of two,) of them and connect those points to get new polygons. You can get mid point of (x0,y0)-(x1,y1) by ((x0+x1)/2,(y0+y1)/2).

Comment: What do you mean by "even" parts, what makes a part even?

Comment: All of the parts have an equal area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below works for any convex 4-sided polygon. When the initial polygon is a parallelogram, the resultant sub-polygons are *by nature* all parallelograms too, all with the same size, i.e. they are even-sized.

Since the desired number of `parts` must be a square number, it means we can simply split the 4-sided polygon horizontally and vertically into `partsPerSide = sqrt(parts)`.

When we split a 4-sided polygon into multiple parts, we may end up with coordinates that are not exact integers. We can simply *round* the value to an integer, but then the pieces wouldn't be exactly even in size. Whether that is acceptable is a matter of choice. Visually, the rounding can be noticed, since the lines won't be 100% straight.

In the code below, we assume that rounding is not acceptable, i.e. we want exact even sizes. If rounding is ok, simply comment out the `if (rounded != delta) throw new ArithmeticException()` code at the end, then call `splitFourSided()` with the desired number of `partsPerSide`.

Enough talk, here is the code:

```java
private static Polygon[][] splitFourSided(Polygon poly, int partsPerSide) {
    if (poly.npoints != 4)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Polygon must be 4-sided");
    if (partsPerSide <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There must be a positive number of parts per side");
    int[][] x = splitFourSided(poly.xpoints, partsPerSide);
    int[][] y = splitFourSided(poly.ypoints, partsPerSide);
    Polygon[][] pieces = new Polygon[partsPerSide][partsPerSide];
    for (int row = 0; row < partsPerSide; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < partsPerSide; col++) {
            pieces[row][col] = new Polygon(
                    new int[] { x[row][col], x[row][col+1], x[row+1][col+1], x[row+1][col] },
                    new int[] { y[row][col], y[row][col+1], y[row+1][col+1], y[row+1][col] },
                    4);
        }
    }
    return pieces;
}
```

```java
private static int[][] splitFourSided(int[] xy, int parts) {
    // To visualize, assume values are [topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft].
    // The 'xy' array is either the x-coordinates or the y-coordinates.
    // First we split left and right sides, e.g. for 3 parts:
    //   From: ┌     To: ┐
    //         ├         ┤
    //         ├         ┤
    //         └         ┘
    // Then we split between those:
    //   ┌─┬─┬─┐
    //   ├─┼─┼─┤
    //   ├─┼─┼─┤
    //   └─┴─┴─┘
    int[] from = splitRange(xy[0], xy[3], parts);
    int[] to = splitRange(xy[1], xy[2], parts);
    int[][] grid = new int[parts + 1][];
    for (int i = 0; i <= parts; i++)
        grid[i] = splitRange(from[i], to[i], parts);
    return grid;
}
```

```java
private static int[] splitRange(int from, int to, int parts) {
    int[] prorated = new int[parts + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= parts; i++)
        prorated[i] = prorate(from, to, i, parts);
    return prorated;
}
```

```java
private static int prorate(int from, int to, int index, int parts) {
    if (index == 0)
        return from;
    if (index == parts)
        return to;
    double delta = (to - (double) from) * index / parts;
    int rounded = (int) Math.round(delta);
    if (rounded != delta)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Cannot prorate to integer value");
    return from + rounded;
}
```

*Test*

```java
int[] x = {38, 100, 80, 18};
int[] y = {50, 50, 100, 100};
Polygon poly = new Polygon(x, y, 4);
splitAndDrawFourSided(g, poly, 2);
```

```java
private static void splitAndDrawFourSided(Graphics g, Polygon poly, int partsPerSide) {
    Polygon[][] pieces = splitFourSided(poly, partsPerSide);
    for (int row = 0; row < partsPerSide; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < partsPerSide; col++)
            g.drawPolygon(pieces[row][col]);
    Graphics gMain = g.create();
    try {
        gMain.setColor(Color.RED);
        gMain.drawPolygon(poly);
    } finally {
        gMain.dispose();
    }
}
```

*Result*

[image]

---

To search for a valid number of parts, we can add a search loop, and change the coordinates so they are only divisible by 7.

```java
int[] x = {37, 100, 79, 16};
int[] y = {50, 50, 99, 99};
Polygon poly = new Polygon(x, y, 4);
for (int partsPerSide : new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 }) {
    try {
        splitAndDrawFourSided(g, poly, partsPerSide);
        break; // stop when successful
    } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") ArithmeticException ignored) {
        continue; // try next number of parts
    }
}
```

*Result*

[image]

---

If we remove the rounding check, that code will of course always just split by 2 parts per side, i.e. into 4 parts. This shows the effect of rounding, e.g. in this case the center row coordinates ended up a bit to the right, causing the black and red lines to not match up. Even without the red line depicting the input parallelogram, the rounding can be noticed. [Anti-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094581/5221149) helps, but it can still be noticed that the vertical lines aren't 100% straight.

[image]
[image]
[image]