# Java : Custom Icon on a JButton doesn't have properly rounded corners

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, rounded-corners

A blank `Icon` was created for coloring purposes and added to a `JButton`.

When attempting to add the Icon to the `JButton`, I am having trouble doing so with rounded corners.

Here is the test code being used.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class ToolBarSample {
  public static void main(final String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JToolBar Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
    toolbar.setRollover(true);

    JButton b2 = new JButton();
    b2.setText("Big Button");
    b2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    b2.setFocusable(false);
    b2.setOpaque(true);
    Dimension buttonSize = new Dimension(340,27);
    b2.setPreferredSize(buttonSize);
    b2.setMinimumSize(buttonSize);
    b2.setMaximumSize(buttonSize);
    b2.setIcon(new EmptyIcon(Color.RED));
    b2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
    b2.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    b2.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    b2.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    
    toolbar.add(b2);
    
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    contentPane.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(550, 350);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  
  public final static class EmptyIcon implements Icon {

      Color color ;

      public EmptyIcon() {
        this(Color.GREEN);
      }
      
      public EmptyIcon(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
      }

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
        {
            System.out.println("Inside paintIcon");
            if(c != null)
            {
                if (this.color != null)
                {
                   g.setColor(this.color);
                }
                g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth() , c.getHeight(), 5, 5);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

When using the following line of code

```
g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth() , c.getHeight(), 0, 0);
```

It generates the following with all corners 90 degrees.

[image]

In order implement the rounded corners, the following was used

```
g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth() , c.getHeight(), 5, 5);
```

The above now generates the following.

[image]

It may look fine, but if you take a closer look, you can see not all the corners are rounded.

Here is a closeup look at the corners. The bottom right corner is actually still a right angle.

[image]

**Question 1**

Is there a simpler way to have this custom Icon always resize itself to the size of the button with properly rounded corners?

**Question 2**

What is the cause for all the corners to appear differently and is there a way to remedy it?

Comment: Try using anti-aliasing. Refer to the accepted answer in this question: [How to draw a decent looking Circle in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094539/how-to-draw-a-decent-looking-circle-in-java) Alternatively, you can draw a `JButton` with rounded corners without using an icon. Did you try Googling for ___round jbutton___ ?

Comment: Nice. Thanks. That works nicely.  I did search for rounded corners but the only items I found involved doing all sorts of calculations which I felt was unnecessary and excessive. I was expecting something more in line to what information was provided in the link. Thanks again.