# How to fill circle with increasing radius?

Tags: algorithm, image, image-processing, geometry

As part of more complex algorithm I need following:

- let's say I have a circle with radius R1 drawn on discrete grid (image) (green on image below)
- I want to draw circle that have radius R2 that is bigger then R1 with one pixel (red on image below).
- At each algorithm step to draw circles with increasing radius in a way that each time I have a filled circle.

[image]

**How can I find the points to fill at each step so at the end of each step I have fully filled circle?**

I have thinking of some circle rasterization algorithm, but this will lead to some gaps in filling.
Another way is to use some mathematical morphology operation like dilation but this seems to be computationally expensive to do.

I am generally looking for way to do this on arbitrary shape but initially circle algorithm will be enough.

Comment: Will each steps shape hide the previous?

Comment: At each step I am looking for the set of points (red) that are added to increase radius with approximately 1 pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current solution for circle.

Based on well known [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)

- create set of points for 1 octant for R1 radius (light green pixels)
- create set of points for 1 octant for R2 radius (dark orange pixels)
- for each row in image compare X coordinate for orange and green pixels and get 0 or 1 (or whatever) number of pixels in-between (light orange).
- repeat for each octant (where for some octants columns instead of rows have to be compared)

This algorithm can be applied for other types of parametric shapes (Bezier curve based for example)

For non-parametric shapes (pixel based) image convolution (dilation) with kernel with central symmetry (circle). In other words for each pixel in shape looking for neighbors in circle with small radius and setting them to be part of the set. (expensive computation)

[image]

Comment: have fun with the parallel Bezier curves!...reckon my way is less computationally expensive, even if you have to burn some memory to create a buffer and compose the result back...

Comment: It maybe that I do not understand it but you way is not less computationally expensive. Is similar to my solution, but doing operations that are not used at the end. Filling green part is not necessary for example. "Burning" memory is not the option. Expected result is list of pixels, not image that have to be processed again to find them.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to draw *and fill* a slightly larger red circle, and then draw and fill the green circle. Then redo on next iteration.

To only draw the 1px border is quite tricky. Your sample image is not even quite consistent. At some places a white pixel occurs diagonally to a green pixel, and in other places that pixel is red.

Edit:

- *borderPixels* = emptySet
- For each green pixel, *p*

  - For each neighbor *n* to *p*

    - If *n* is white

      - Add *n* to *borderPixels`
- Do whatever you like with *borderPixels* (such as color them red)

Comment: Image is just approximate example of what it looks like. I am ok of algorithm that can vary 1-2 pixels at some points especially for arbitrary shapes. This "front line" is then used to check against some other graphics objects for crossings.

Comment: Thanks, this algo was my first solution, but finding "For each neighbor" is basically a dilation with 3x3 mask and max operation of it. I was thinking that there exist some less computationally expensive algo.

Comment: I don't believe so if you're dealing with arbitrary shapes.

Comment: cute algorithm. I guess it can be optimized a bit so that you don't scan all internal green pixels but advance only on the border ones. You may need to maintain 2 sets `innerBorder` (greens), `outerBorder` (whites). Need to initialize the `innerBorder` somehow though to start the algorithm

Comment: @davka, no, not if the shape has holes. (@Ross pointed out that the circle was just an example, and that he's actually dealing with arbitrary shapes)

Comment: @davka, yes I am looking for some algorithm that will not check all internal points. For holes there is another inner set of points.

Comment: If you *want* to handle figures with holes, you need to inspect inner pixels (how else would you find a 1-pixel-hole?!), if you *don't* need to handle shapes with holes, just follow the border of the green pixels.

Comment: @aioobe. I just realized that this solution have problem to keep the shape after many iterations the same. If you iteratively add only neighbor pixels it will not be circle at some point. There have to be added some times 0 some times 1 pixel at different points.

Comment: Sure. Do you always have an idealized vector representation of the shape? (Because if you only have "pixel"-representation of the shape, then it's not a circle to start with anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to draw a circle/shape with a 2pixel wide red border, and then draw a green filled circle/shape with NO border. Which should leave an ***approximately*** 1px wide edge.
It depends on how whatever technique you use resolves lines to pixels.

Circle algorithms tend to be optimised for drawing circles.....[See the link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022178/how-to-make-a-circle-on-a-grid/1022182#1022182)

Answer (score 0):

Draw the circles with radii 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ... and fill the space in between them as needed, or draw all radii 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... and fill the holes with proper timing proportional to distance to the center.

Both method need to draw the next radius circle early and use it in next step.